# Visual Studio C# Command line compiler takes long to run, taking site down

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012

Every site my asp.net site starts, Visual Studio C# Command line compiler starts running. It takes more CPU space and continue to run for few hours.
While it is running my sites does not open.

I facing this problem very badly and need some help.
My Server with Xenon CPU, 8 GB Ram and windows 2012 installed on it.

Thanks

Comment: I had a problem like that also.try stopping the iis pool / stop iis server , after you start it again then try to open the page again. i need to do that every time i update my site otherwise i have the same problem , only for me it dos not take hours to get an error

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing compile at run-time? Consider pre-compiling the application to solve this problem.

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464(v=vs.110).aspx